# Joomla plugin : how to get article title and article id

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-template, joomla-sef-urls

I have developed on simple plugin in Joomla 1.6
I stuck at : How to get article title and article url.

I am getting no output if tried to print below statement:

```
echo $article->title;
echo $article->id;
```

I have written this in php file, not used MVC architecture.
Is there any other settings need to do in Joomla admin side ?

Please suggest your pointers for extracting article title and article url.

Thanks in advance!

Pravin

Comment: To check if the code is currently displaying an article, make sure `JRequest::getCmd('view', '')` returns `"article"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**i tried :**

```
public function onContentPrepare($context,&$article, &$params, $limitstart) {
 echo JRequest::getVar('id');
}
```

**Still I am not getting the id. Is this right?**

The article is loaded in your second argument (`$article`). Being on this event (`onContentPrepare`), the only property you can access is `$article->text`.

For suiting your purpose (getting the article id and title) you will want to use another event, called "`onContentBeforeDisplay`".

```
public function onContentBeforeDisplay($context, &$article, &$params, $limitstart)
```

Here you have (again) the article passed through the second argument, but now you have access to properties like `$article->id`, `$article->title` and many others.

For future references on content events, take a look at the file "*plugins\content\example\example.php*"

Answer (score 14):

In order to get the article ID you have to write the following:

```
echo JRequest::getVar('id');
```

For the title, you just take the id you got, load the article object

```
$blabla = $article->load(ID);
echo $blabla->get('title');
```

Comment: i tried : public function onContentPrepare($context,&$article, &$params, $limitstart)
    { 
    echo JRequest::getVar('id');

    }                                                                Still I am not getting id...is this write ?

Answer (score 9):

It seems `JRequest` is deprecated in 2.5 & 3.x as indicated in the [Deprecated Elements](http://api.joomla.org/cms-2.5/deprecated.html) list.

I would rather use the following:

```
$article_id = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('id');
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use for getting active article title like this

```
$menu =& Jsite::getMenu(); echo $menu->getActive()->title;
```

may this help.

Comment: That gets the current menu title.

Answer (score -5):

To get Joomla article id use this...

```
<?php echo JRequest::getVar('Itemid'); ?>
```

In the previous answer someone used `id` instead of `Itemid`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Itemid is used for menu not for article.