# How to get the date of creation and view count of an article in Joomla?

Tags: date, joomla, metadata, joomla-article

Can somebody hint the follow: I have to insert in my custom module oа Joomla (HTML essentially) the service info, which is shown by Joomla usually - I need the date of creation and the number of how this article was viewed?

Comment: What do you mean: the number of how this article was viewed ?

Comment: Yes, I do. Some PHP-code $count = JFactory("article").getHowManyViewver

Comment: What's the joomla version your developing on ?

Comment: sql query provided by Okonomiyaki3000 is your best bet and please o please upgrade to Joomla 2.5 if you get the chance ;)

Comment: @Lodder See that little 'up' arrow next to my answer?

Comment: o yeah...made use of it now ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can run a very simple query to get this:

```
SELECT `created`, `hits` FROM #__content WHERE `id` = <your article id>
```

`created` is the creation date, `hits` is it number of times the article has been viewed.

Comment: you can get the article id with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056886/joomla-plugin-how-to-get-article-tile-and-article-id
to make it dynamic !